# What units are the values in /proc/partitions and /sys/dev/block/<block>/size?

Tags: filesystems, partition, proc, size, units

I have a sample emmc block info from an android device

> From `/proc/partitions`

```
major minor  #blocks  name
 179    1    5120    mmcblk0p1
```

Using my little intelligence I am assuming `/proc/partitions` uses blocks since it says partition 1 has 5120 blocks

> From `/sys/dev/block/179:0/mmcblk0p1/size`

```
10240
```

It is seeming the partition values in /sys/…/size are double the values of /proc/partitions. Hence why are they different hence what the units in both of them?

Comment: The former should be 1024 byte. The latter I believe it's logic sector size of your disk. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/proc/partitions` shows the size in 1024-byte blocks.

`/sys/dev/block/*/*/size` shows the size in 512-byte sectors.

Both irrespective of the logical/physical block/sector size of the device.

---

For the 1st, you can look in the `proc(5)` manpage:

> `/proc/partitions`
>
> Contains  the  major and minor numbers of each partition as well
>   as the number of 1024-byte blocks and the partition name.

For the 2nd, it certainly should be documented *somewhere* but you can also look directly at the Linux source code in `block/partition-generic.c`:

```
ssize_t part_size_show(struct device *dev,
                       struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
        struct hd_struct *p = dev_to_part(dev);
        return sprintf(buf, "%llu\n",(unsigned long long)part_nr_sects_read(p));
...
static DEVICE_ATTR(size, 0444, part_size_show, NULL);
```

and how it relates to the code which generates the `/proc/partitions` info in `block/genhd.c`:

```
static int show_partition(struct seq_file *seqf, void *v)
{
        ...
        while ((part = disk_part_iter_next(&piter)))
                seq_printf(seqf, "%4d  %7d %10llu %s\n",
                           MAJOR(part_devt(part)), MINOR(part_devt(part)),
                           (unsigned long long)part_nr_sects_read(part) >> 1,
                           disk_name(sgp, part->partno, buf));
        disk_part_iter_exit(&piter);
...
static const struct seq_operations partitions_op = {
        ...
        .show   = show_partition
```

Both are using `part_nr_sects_read()` which for the case of `/proc/partitions` is divided by 2 (with `>> 1`).

`part_nr_sects_read()` retrieves the `nr_sects` field of the `struct hd_struct`, which is always in 512-byte sectors, irrespective of the sector/block size of the device. For instance, you can look at how `drivers/block/nbd.c` uses the `set_capacity()` function (which sets the same `nr_sects` field) with the byte size divided by 512 (with `>> 9`):

```
static void nbd_size_update(struct nbd_device *nbd)
{
        ...
        set_capacity(nbd->disk, config->bytesize >> 9);
```

Comment: Thank you; I've been looking for the canonical answer to this question for an hour.