# Calculate disk Byte size exclusively from /sys/block/

Tags: partition, disk, block-device

If we want to get the byte size of a block device or one of its partitions without calling any binary, and in a way that will always work, is it correct to do:

```
/sys/block/sda/sda1/size
or /sys/block/sda/size
```

Multiplied by :

```
/sys/block/sda/queue/physical_block_size
```

Or is it **logical_block_size** or **hw_sector_size** ?

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

After more research I finally found the answer:

> Linux always considers sectors to be 512 bytes long independently of
>   the devices real block size.

According to the source:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/types.h?id=v4.4-rc6#n121

I was led there by this comment:
[Determine the size of a block device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52215/determine-the-size-of-a-block-device#comment112867_52219)

So as silly as it may seem the [size] should simply be multiplied by 512.

I just hope it will still be a correct assumption 15 years from now, because I don't want my programs to be broken. **physical_block_size** seems wrong because it can sometimes be 4096 as I found with some Googling, but maybe it is still worth reading **logical_block_size** or **hw_sector_size** even if it will always be 512? Any comments on this?

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512959/308316